# Iterate params, call a method and pass the results to another function

Tags: c#

I have a function that uses the params keyword to allow me to pass multiple objects to it:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> GetMyObjects(params FilterObject[] filters)
  return service.GetObjectsFromDatabase(filters);
}
```

So it can be called like:

```
GetMyObjects(filter1, filter2, filter3);
```

My issue is that I need to convert each object passed to the function into a different type before calling a second function which also uses the params keyword. The second function looks like:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> GetObjectsFromDatabase(params AnotherType[] filters) 
{
  _database.GetObjectsFromDatabase(filters);
}
```

I assume I need to loop through each parameter and call my method which performs the conversion, however how do I then store each converted object to be able to pass them to the next function?

I imagined it would be something like:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> GetMyObjects(params FilterObject[] filters)
  List<AnotherType> myList = new List<AnotherType>();
  foreach (FilterObject f in FilterObjects) {
   AnotherType a = f.ConvertToAnotherType();
   myList.Add(a);
  }
  return service.GetMyObjects(myList);
}
```

But that didn't work as the second function doesn't accept a List. What is the correct way of passing these objects?

Comment: It accepts array, not list, so give it array.

Comment: You can call `service.GetMyObjects(myList.ToArray())`

Comment: Why are you converting each object anyway, why not implement your filters in such a way that you can use them for both purposes? Converting objects is a very bad smell

Comment: @Glubus It's a dumbed down example I've used for the question but the real world problem is that the objects need to be serialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)-array is an array not a list, so use:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> GetMyObjects(params FilterObject[] filters)
  AnotherType[] atArray = filters.Select(f => f.ConvertToAnotherType()).ToArray();
  return service.GetMyObjects( atArray );
}
```

instead of LINQ you could also use `Array.ConvertAll`:

```
AnotherType[] atArray = Array.ConvertAll(filters, f => f.ConvertToAnotherType());
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to call `.ToArray()` on list but it'll iterate the collection twice which adds unnecessary overhead. You can do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> GetMyObjects(params FilterObject[] filters)
{
   var myArray = new AnotherType[filters.Length];
   for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) 
   {
      myArray[i] = filters[i].ConvertToAnotherType();
   }
   return service.GetMyObjects(myArray);
}
```

Or use LINQ .Select as suggested by Tim Schmelter